# Exporting of tooltip in highcharts

Tags: graph, highcharts, export

How can I export the individual tooltip in highcharts as a image. I know how to export the full graph but I have no idea how to export the individual tooltip. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In general it's not supported, but of course possible to achieve. In Highcharts you have access to `chart.tooltip.refresh(point || points_array)` which can be called in callback:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5, 15, 14, 25, 54]
    }]
}, function(chart) {
     chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].data[0]);   
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kaLa5jm9/